# jQuery datepicker year dropdown problem in yearRange

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({yearRange: "1970:2019"});
```

unable to see dropdown list of years

Comment: you might have to add `changeYear:true,` but it's only a guess

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get or set the yearRange option, after initialization:

```
// Get
var yearRange = $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "yearRange" );

// Set
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "yearRange", "2002:2012" );
```

Comment: Not working. Error method option does not exist in datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It works for me

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
      changeYear:true,
      yearRange: "1970:2019"
    });
});
```

Comment: Not working. Whenever i set yearRange, year selection dropdown disappear